# How to use stripe elements without wepacker in rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, hotwire-rails

I'm using Rails 7.0.0.alpha2 and I'd like to integrate stripe element (consume from stripe). I don't have a webpacker but I have hotwire together to importmap (responsible for javascript packages) and stimulus(Javascript Framework)

I am a bit lost as I have not been able to normally use javascript to integrate stripe internally to my application

If someone has used stripe elements together with rails 7 (or together with stimulus js) and could give me some help I would be very grateful

Comment: Can you share your importmap configs, and also share whatever errors you're seeing? There are several places this integration could go wrong

Answer (score 3):

You need to pin the package with `./bin/importmap pin @stripe/stripe-js`

Then you will be able to load it with `import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'` wherever you want to use it; I suggest a [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev) controller. If you prefer to set it up with vanilla and you are unsure how to load custom files see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548841/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-new-rails-7-project)

For particular `stripe-js` usage questions, please refer to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js?activeTab=readme)

Once you have an instance of Stripe, you can create an [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create) instance and so a [card](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card)(or the element you need)

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup with Rails 7, Hotwire Stimulus, Hotwire Turbolinks and importmaps. I tried to use Stripe together with importmaps, by pinning it like this:

```
./bin/importmap pin stripe
```

And in the Stimulus controller I imported it like this:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
```

Unfortunately, I got a lot of errors. For example this one `TypeError: stripe.elements is not a function`. That's why I had to integrate it the old way. I removed Stripe completely from my importmaps and import it now in the HTML header likes this:

```
<% if session[:menu].to_s.eql?( 'orga/settings/payment' ) %>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<% end %>
```

I still have a Stimulus controller for Stripe and in the `connect()` I'm initializing the form. All the JavaScript which used to be in the HTML page, now is in the Stimulus controller. That works fine.
I hope my answer is helpful.