# How to add custom JS file to new rails 7 project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I created new rails 7 project `rails new my_project` and have a problem to include my custom JS file to be processed by rails.

my "javascript/application.js"

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "chartkick"
import "Chart.bundle"
import "custom/uni_toggle"
```

my custom JS file: "javascript/custom/uni_toggle.js"

```
function uniToggleShow() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".uni-toggle").forEach(e => e.classList.remove("hidden"))
}

function uniToggleHide() {
    console.log("uni toggle hide")
    document.querySelectorAll(".uni-toggle").forEach(e => e.classList.add("hidden"))
}

window.uniToggleShow = uniToggleShow
window.uniToggleHide = uniToggleHide
```

I'm using in my layout `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>`

and my "config/importmap.rb"

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

Answer (score 94):

```text
1. Quickstart            - quick things you should know
2. `pin_all_from`        - a few details
3. `pin`                   ...
4. Run in a console      - when you need to figure stuff out
5. Relative imports      - don't do it, unless you want to
6. Examples              - to make it extra clear
```

If you're **not** using `importmap-rails`, really, you should not have any issues. Add a file then `import "./path/to/file"`. Make sure to run `bin/dev` to compile your javascript if you're using `jsbundling-rails`.

If you're using `importmap-rails`, there is no compilation, every single file has to be served individually in development and production, and every *import* has to be mapped to a url for browser to fetch.

`pin` and `pin_all_from` is a  rails way of constructing an [`importmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap). Imports are mapped to local files through an asset url. So just keep in mind, `import "something"` could map to url `/assets/file-123.js` which could map to file `app/some_asset_path/file.js` or in production `public/assets/file-123.js`:

```rb
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application":                  "/assets/application-da9b182f12cdd2de0b86de67fc7fde8d1887a7d9ffbde46937f8cd8553cb748d.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails":        "/assets/turbo.min-49f8a244b039107fa6d058adce740847d31bdf3832c043b860ebcda099c0688c.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus":           "/assets/stimulus-a1299f07b3a1d1083084767c6e16a178a910487c81874b80623f7f2e48f99a86.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading":   "/assets/stimulus-loading-6024ee603e0509bba59098881b54a52936debca30ff797835b5ec6a4ef77ba37.js",
    "controllers/application":      "/assets/controllers/application-44e5edd38372876617b8ba873a82d48737d4c089e5180f706bdea0bb7b6370be.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-29468750494634340c5c12678fe2cdc3bee371e74ac4e9de625cdb7a89faf11b.js",
    "controllers":                  "/assets/controllers/index-e70bed6fafbd4e4aae72f8c6fce4381d19507272ff2ff0febb3f775447accb4b.js",
  }#    ^                             ^
   #    |                             |
   #  names you use to import        urls browser uses to get it
   #    |                             ^ 
   #    |                             |
   #    `------>  mapped to  ---------'
}</script>
```

Once you have an importmap you have to `import` the things you need. Importmap doesn't load anything, it is just a configuration.

---

### Quickstart

Let's say we've added a *plugin* directory:

```rb
app/
└── javascript/
   ├── application.js   # <= imports go here and other js files
   └── plugin/
      ├── app.js
      └── index.js
config/
└── importmap.rb        # <= pins go here
```

Pin a single file:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin "plugin/app"
pin "plugin/index"

# app/javascript/application.js
import "plugin/app"     # which maps to a url which maps to a file
import "plugin/index"
```

or pin all the files in *plugin* directory and subdirectories:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin"

# app/javascript/application.js
import "plugin/app"
import "plugin"         # will import plugin/index.js
```

**Do not use relative imports**, such as `import "./plugin/app"`, it may work in development, but it will break in production.
See the output of `bin/importmap json` to know what you can import and verify *importmap.rb* config.

**Do not precompile** in development, it will serve precompiled assets from `public/assets` which do not update when you make changes.
Run `bin/rails assets:clobber` to remove precompiled assets.

In case something doesn't work, *app/javascript* directory has to be in:
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
and `app/assets/config/manifest.js` as `//= link_tree ../../javascript .js`

---

Pinning your files doesn't make them load. They have to be imported in `application.js`:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
import "plugin"
```

Alternatively, if you want to split up your bundle, you can use a separate module tag in your layout:

```rb
<%= javascript_import_module_tag "plugin" %>
```

or templates:

```rb
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "plugin" %>
<% end %>

# add this to the end of the <head> tag:
# <%= yield :head %>
```

You can also add another entrypoint in addition to `application.js`, say you've added `app/javascript/admin.js`. You can import it with all the pins:

```rb
# this doesn't `import` application.js anymore
<%= javascript_importmap_tags "admin" %>
```

Because `application` pin has `preload: true` option set by default it will issue a request to load `application.js` file, even when you override `application` entrypoint with `admin`. Preloading and importing are two separate things, one does not cause the other. Remove `preload` option to avoid unnecessary request.

---

### pin_all_from(dir, under: nil, to: nil, preload: false)

Pins all the files in a directory and subdirectories.

*https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.1.2/lib/importmap/map.rb#L33*

```rb
def pin_all_from(dir, under: nil, to: nil, preload: false)
  clear_cache
  @directories[dir] = MappedDir.new(dir: dir, under: under, path: to, preload: preload)
end
```

`dir` - Path relative to *Rails.root* or an absolute path.

Options:

`:under` - Optional<sup>[1]</sup> pin prefix. Required if you have `index.js` file.

`:to` - Optional<sup>[1]</sup> path to asset. Falls [back](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.1.2/lib/importmap/map.rb#L148) to *:under* option. Required if *:under* is omitted.
This path is relative to *Rails.application.config.assets.paths*.

`:preload` - Adds a *modulepreload* link if set to `true`:

```
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo-5605bff731621f9ca32b71f5270be7faa9ccb0c7c810187880b97e74175d85e2.js">
```

1. *note: either `:under` or `:to` is required*

---

To pin all the files in the *plugin* directory:

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin"

# NOTE: `index.js` file gets a special treatment, instead
#       of pinning `plugin/index` it is just `plugin`.
{
  "imports": {
    "plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
    "plugin": "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
  }
}
```

Here is how it all fits together:
*(if something doesn't work, take your options and follow the arrows, especially the `path_to_asset` part, you can try it in the console, see below)*

```rb
   "plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb...4145d8113cf788597.js"
#   ^      ^      ^
#   |      |      |  
# :under   |      `-path_to_asset("plugin/app.js")
#          |                       ^      ^
#          |                       |      |
#          |..       (:to||:under)-'      |
#  "#{dir}/app.js"                        |
#          '''''`-------------------------'
```

`:to` option might not be obvious here. It is useful if *:under* option is changed, which will make `path_to_asset` fail to find *app.js*.

For example, *:under* option can be anything you want, but *:to* option has to be a path that asset pipeline, *Sprockets*, can find (see *Rails.application.config.assets.paths*) and also precompile (see *app/assets/config/manifest.js*).

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/plugin", under: "@plug", to: "plugin"

# Outputs these pins
#
#   "@plug/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391b1...16beb14ce788597.js"
#   "@plug": "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb91...4ebeb14ce788597.js"
#
# and can be used like this
#
#   import "@plug";
#   import "@plug/app";
```

Specifying absolute path will bypass asset pipeline:

```rb
pin_all_from("app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin", to: "/plugin")

#   "plugin/app": "/plugin/app.js"
#   "plugin": "/plugin/index.js"
#
# NOTE: It is up to you to set up `/plugin/*` route and serve these files.
```

---

### pin(name, to: nil, preload: false)

Pins a single file.

*https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.1.2/lib/importmap/map.rb#L28*

```rb
def pin(name, to: nil, preload: false)
  clear_cache
  @packages[name] = MappedFile.new(name: name, path: to || "#{name}.js", preload: preload)
end
```

`name` - Name of the pin.

Options:

`:to` - Optional path to asset. Falls back to `{name}.js`. This path is relative to *Rails.application.config.assets.paths*.

`:preload` - Adds a *modulepreload* link if set to `true`

---

When pinning a local file, specify *name* relative to *app/javascript* directory (or *vendor* or any other asset directory).

```rb
pin "plugin/app"
pin "plugin/index"

{
  "imports": {
    "plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
    "plugin/index": "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
  }
}
```

Here is how it fits together:

```rb
   "plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb...16cebeb14ce788597.js"
#   ^             ^
#   |             |  
#  name           `-path_to_asset("plugin/app.js")
#                                  ^
#                                  |
#              (:to||"#{name}.js")-'
```

If you want to change the *name* of the pin, `:to` option is required   to give *path_to_asset* a valid file location.

For example, to get the same pin for *index.js* file as the one we get from *pin_all_from*:

```rb
pin "plugin", to: "plugin/index"

{
  "imports": {
    "plugin": "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
  }
}
```

---

### Run in a console

You can mess around with `Importmap` in the console, it's faster to debug and learn what works and what doesn't:

```rb
>> helper.path_to_asset("plugin/app.js")
=> "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"

>> map = Importmap::Map.new
>> map.pin_all_from("app/javascript/plugin", under: "plugin")
>> puts map.to_json(resolver: helper)
{
  "imports": {
    "plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
    "plugin": "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
  }
}

>> map.pin("application")
>> puts map.to_json(resolver: helper)
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-8cab2d9024ef6f21fd55792af40001fd4ee1b72b8b7e14743452fab1348b4f5a.js"
  }
}

# Importmap from config/importmap.rb
>> Rails.application.importmap
```

---

### Relative/absolute imports

Relative/absolute imports could work, if you make the correct mapping:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin "/assets/plugin/app", to: "plugin/app.js"
```

```
// app/javascript/application.js
import "./plugin/app"
```

*application.js* is mapped to digested */assets/application-123.js*,  because `./plugin/app` is relative to */assets/application-123.js*, it should be correctly resolved to `/assets/plugin/app` which has an importmap that we made with our pin:

```
"/assets/plugin/app": "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
```

This should also just work:

```
// app/javascript/plugin/index.js
import "./app"
```

However, while `import-maps` [support](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps#mapping-away-hashes-in-script-filenames) all the relative and absolute imports, this doesn't seem to be the intended use case in `importmap-rails`.

---

### Examples

This should cover just about everything:

```text
.
├── app/
│   └── javascript/
│       ├── admin.js
│       ├── application.js
│       ├── extra/
│       │   └── nested/
│       │       └── directory/
│       │           └── special.js
│       └── plugin/
│           ├── app.js
│           └── index.js
└── vendor/
    └── javascript/
        ├── downloaded.js
        └── package/
            └── vendored.js
```

Output is from running `bin/importmap json`:

```rb
# this is the only time when both `to` and `under` options can be omitted
# you don't really want to do this, at least not for `app/javascript`
pin_all_from "app/javascript"
pin_all_from "vendor/javascript"

"admin":                          "/assets/admin-761ee3050e9046942e5918c64dbfee795eeade86bf3fec34ec126c0d43c931b0.js",
"application":                    "/assets/application-d0d262731ff4f756b418662f3149e17b608d2aab7898bb983abeb669cc73bf2e.js",
"extra/nested/directory/special": "/assets/extra/nested/directory/special-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
"plugin/app":                     "/assets/plugin/app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
"plugin":                         "/assets/plugin/index-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
"downloaded":                     "/assets/downloaded-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js",
"package/vendored":               "/assets/package/vendored-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
```

Note the difference:

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra", under: "extra"    # `to: "extra"` is implied
"extra/nested/directory/special": "/assets/extra/nested/directory/special-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
 ^

pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra", to: "extra"
"nested/directory/special": "/assets/extra/nested/directory/special-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
 ^

pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra", under: "@name", to: "extra"
"@name/nested/directory/special": "/assets/extra/nested/directory/special-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
 ^
```

Note the pattern:

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra",                  under: "extra"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested",           under: "extra/nested"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested/directory", under: "extra/nested/directory"
```

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra",                  to: "extra"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested",           to: "extra/nested"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested/directory", to: "extra/nested/directory"
```

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra",                  under: "@name", to: "extra"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested",           under: "@name", to: "extra/nested"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/extra/nested/directory", under: "@name", to: "extra/nested/directory"
```

Same exact thing works for vendor:

```rb
pin_all_from "vendor/javascript/package", under: "package"
# etc
```

Single files are easy:

```rb
pin "admin"
pin "application"
pin "extra/nested/directory/special"
pin "@extra/special", to: "extra/nested/directory/special"

pin "downloaded"
pin "renamed", to: "downloaded"
```

When *pin_all_from* fails:

```rb
# if you ever tried this, it doesn't work:
# pin_all_from "app/javascript", under: "@app", to: ""
# but it can be done:
app_js = Rails.root.join("app/javascript")
app_js.glob("**/*.js").each do |path|
  name = path.relative_path_from(app_js).to_s.chomp(".js")
  pin "@app/#{name}", to: name
end
# useful for things like `app/components`
```

Comment: This post deserves all the upvotes. Thank you.

Comment: @cesoid if you want to make relative imports work, see the very last code snippet to get an idea of what to do outside of the defaults. but nothing stopping you from making `import "pallete"` or `import "@fractal/pallete"` work: `pin_all_from "app/javascript/fractal_viewer", to: "fractal_viewer"` or `pin_all_from "app/javascript/fractal_viewer", under: "@fractal", to: "fractal_viewer"`. but consider that changing your imports for an hour is easier than debugging some edge case issues with relative imports. you'd be better off sticking with esbuild in that case.

Comment: Has anything changed since this answer that makes it easier to use relative imports? Or is there some effective equivalent that allows me to not hardcode the directory name of large isolated features of my site in all the imports (e.g., avoid import 'fractal_viewer/palette.js')? [Edit: Removed my pointless rambling.]

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I ended up doing this: `def pin_all_relative(dir_name) ; pin_all_from "app/javascript/#{dir_name}", under: "#{Rails.application.config.assets.prefix}/#{dir_name}", to: dir_name ; end` and then calling it once per "component". To explain: My site has over 200 of its own modules organized into directories several layers deep, and even the deepest ones will sometimes import without even referencing their parent directory. In total there are about 600 import statements which I would have to change without a simple find/replace, and I would lose a bit of flexibility and reusability.

Comment: To explain further: The relative imports work without importmap, but in development it takes up to 10 seconds for a page to load because it isn't retrieving from static assets. This may partly be because puma doesn't support http2, but using caddy to serve them with http2 didn't speed things up. My last resort was to "precompile" the javascript in dev because this puts them in static fingerprinted files in assets, so the 10 second load only happens once, and subsequent loads only grab files that have changed. I have no idea how much of this applies to production, but I'll soon find out.

Comment: @cesoid maybe this is the solution for you: sprockets: `Completed 200 OK in 110378ms (Allocations: 244013006)` vs [propshaft](https://github.com/rails/propshaft): `Completed 200 OK in 5355ms (Allocations: 6575854)`.  (10k files, 1k lines each).

Comment: This answer is like a missing manual for importmaps.

Comment: This has to be in the official Rails docs. Especially the part about relative imports from `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`.  It's not obvious IMHO. Thank you for all the effort you put to this comment

Comment: That's the most complete answer I have ever seen, congrats @Alex.
However, I'm still unable to make it work.

I have a `app/javascript/custom/custom.js` file and regardless the way I try to pin it, it doesn't work. I tried checking the console and trying many different ways but none of them puts my file in `bin/import map json` or `puts map.to_json(resolver: helper)` response.

The only thing I see that might be different in my side is that my `app/javascript/`and `vendor/javascript` are Pathnames in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`'s responses.

Any idea what I'm missing?
Thx!

Comment: @andrer0cha `pin "custom/custom"` or `pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"` if that doesn't work, the only thing i can think of is a typo somewhere, or manifest.js is misconfigured in which case you should be getting an error or importmap complaining about missing path.

Comment: @Alex, `pin "custom/custom"` worked, thank you!! The main issue was that the server was being initialized set to `production`, and I didn't realize it.
It's all working now, thank you so much!!

Comment: If I do the same thing creating a subfolder "plugin", I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "plugin". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". in console

Comment: @Alfredo did you create `plugin/index.js` file? just check `bin/importmap json` to see what you can import

Comment: Hi @Ales, yes, I found that the problem was in the manifest.js file, that did not point to the correct folder

Comment: @Alex I've two inherent questions: 1) What special treatment the index.js file gets? 2) How does importmap work with `export` statements like [`export * from "./useControllerMixinName"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771828) in an index.js file?

Comment: @user502052 1) not much, other than it gets mapped to a directory name: `import "plugin"` will import "plugin/index.js" 2) relative name is a problem

Answer (score 27):

Was also having trouble adding custom JS files in my Rails 7 app. I even followed DHH video --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0 but still was facing difficulties. The following steps worked for me:

1. Go to **config/importmap.rb** and add the following:

   `pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"`
2. Go to app/javascript/application.js file and add the following:

   `import "custom/main"`
3. In **'app/javascript'** directory, add 'custom' folder.
4. In **'app/javascript/custom'** directory add your custom js file 'main.js'.
5. Run In your terminal:

   **rails assets:precompile**
6. Start your rails server.
   Voilà

Comment: this kind of works but running `rails assets:precompile` after any edits to a custom JS file cannot be the correct behaviour

Comment: @depassion I think that video is a little old now. You don't have to precompile anymore.

Comment: I found this question and followed everything here, the javascript file but what worked for me was putting the custom javasript at the bottom of my view file. So what is the difference or the "right" way??

Comment: The 2nd point shold be import "./custom/main"

Comment: no it should not. an import like "./custom/main" end up pointing directly to the assets folder. they will break in production.

Comment: In development it's better to clobber the assets and never precompile them again. Then start the server with "bin/dev" instead of "rails server". That way assets are automatically updated when they change.

Answer (score 22):

After watching DHH [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0) I found the last piece of the puzzle.

To make my custom JS code work, I just added this line to the "confing/importmap.rb"

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

Comment: so in this way, we add our js file in the "importmap", but what if I have multiple layouts and both have different js files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use importmap, do what people have answer before.

But if you add the file in the importmap it means that in every layout, the file will be loaded, but if you only want to add single JS file, my suggestion is to use a simple , with [javascript_include_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag) like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'filename' %>
```