# Rails 7 sharing stimulus controller functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, stimulusjs, import-maps

I'm trying to share stimulus controller functions with other controllers but the files are not being found because of the asset pipeline digest.

Parent (app/javascript/controllers/a_shared_controller.js)

```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  // some shared functions
}
```

Child

```
import Controller from "./a_shared_controller"
```

This works fine in development. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use relative imports. When you pin all controllers like this:

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

You get these `import-maps` generated:

```html
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "controllers/application":      "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers":                  "/assets/controllers/index-ed00704a3bfd9aebb7c818233ee5411c3ce8050f411b77ec27c4252ded99a59c.js",
  }
<!-- ^ this is what you can import -->
}</script>
```

`application.js` would be an example of a shared file, it is imported in `index.js`:

```js
import { application } from "controllers/application"
//                           ^
// NOTE: the name of the generated importmap is used to import
```

If you add another file, don't add `_controller.js` as it would load automatically in `index.js` (unless that's what you want).

---

I have another answer explaining why relative paths don't work and how to *maybe* make them work:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136675/207090*

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this and it didn't work at the time, but yes, the paths must match the importmap json output. Thanks!