# How to use custom JS on a Rails 7 view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to add custom JS to my Rails 7 project. I followed the instructions on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71303435/8377123).

But I'm still not able to use custom JS in my view.

Here is my main.js:

```
function sayHi() {
    console.log("hi");
}

window.sayHi = sayHi;
```

Here is my view (index.html.erb):

```
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="sayHi()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

When I click the button, in the console it just says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHi is not defined
```

I'm really not sure how to access the custom JS from my view.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe9lqxcdj1k14j5/RailsWithJS.zip?dl=0) is a link to my project I uploaded to DropBox.

Comment: Better solution -  just stop writing JS like its 2005 and [attach an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You'll thank me later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose the function to the global scope.

```js
window.sayHi = sayHi;
```

Answer (score 2):

So I am going to post this as a complete answer to anyone who wants to add javascript to their Rails 7 project:

1. Create your custom JS file in `app/javascript/custom/main.js` (or
   whatever file name you like):

   ```
   function sayHi() {
       console.log("hi");
   }

   window.sayHi = sayHi;  // You must have this to expose your functions
   ```

   (or you can use an event hanlder instead)
2. Go to `config/importmap.rb` and add the following:

   ```
   pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
   ```
3. Go to `app/javascript/application.js` file and add the following:

   ```
   import "custom/main"
   ```
4. Run In your terminal:

   ```
   rails assets:precompile
   ```
5. Start your rails server. Voilà

Answer (score 0):

The above answers show how to add a JS script globally. If you need to add a script only to a specific view you can do it in the following way:

1. Create your custom JS file in app/javascript/custom/yourfile.js:

```
const btnClick = document.getElementById("btnClick")
console.log(btnClick)
```

2. Use the javascript_include_tag helper at the end of your ERB view to include it:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom/events.js' %>
```

That's it