# I am using rails 7 importmap but error is generated javascript XXX function is not defined on custom js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7

Recently I am learning to use rails7, but when I use importmap to refer to my js file,
I always get an error: [ testalert is not defined ], please help me

testjs.js is my js file

app/javascript/testjs.js

```
.....
  function testalert(){
    alert('call from testjs');
  }
```

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
......
<input type='button' onclick="testalert();" value='test alert'>
```

importmap.rb

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "testjs", preload: true
```

application.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "testjs"
```

app/assets/config/manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
 ......
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( testjs.js )
```

when i click the web page button [test alert] should pop up a alert windows ,but always get the error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85XwV.png)

the html head
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAzbS.png)

Does anyone know why and how to fix it  , Thank you

System configuration
Rails version:
**rails 7.0.5**
Ruby version:
**ruby 3.1.2**

I have followed
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548841/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-new-rails-7-project/72855705#72855705](https://stackoverflow.com) but the error still occurs