# Importmaps in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, import-maps

I am new to rails 7 and dont know where to put my custom js files.
Now I know the importmaps are used to get third part javascript libraries via cdn's and we include in our application.js file. But suppose if I have my custom js files which are shared across multiple views, then in asset pipeline, I used to put them in app/assets/javascripts and if using webpacker, used to keep in app/javascript and then arrange accordingly with pack tags or include tags. But here using importmaps, where should I put these custom js files as importmaps are just for third party js libraries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855705/207090

Comment: You can check out Stimulus Controllers [here](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers)