# Rails 7: How to add custom javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I read carefully [How to add custom JS file to new rails 7 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548841/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-new-rails-7-project). That post describe How to do it. My onw try and is still failing

My javascript tree. custom folder and index.js were added by me.

```bash
.
├── application.js
├── controllers
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── hello_controller.js
│   └── index.js
└── custom
    └── index.js

2 directories, 5 files
```

My  **app/javascript/application.js**

```rb
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "custom"
```

My **app/javascript/custom/custom.js**

```bash
function btn_project_show() {
    alert('culodemono');    
}
```

My **config/importmap.rb**

```rb
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

Top of html source code (After precompile. **assets/custom/custom-fd29fe543537735de09c23dfa7241cdd8e47c8f9fd71e89211b591fc7c12fd8c.js** is perfectly accesible)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="J96RvzdbOjB5WdfZtE0-eFIoJpISdZP3N32YPIiotPmIsTBlGyL69NlqShdPCadKOv4ReV2PFoGdMZ9CH1kxdw" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-ed7f657c82113ab3654e0f1c0a9fb78eb9439717ba426d64a05914a481e366bf.css" data-turbo-track="reload" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendor-342cc5ede18e0d08cf0a816961342ad3262763c3e440dbabc6bca4f058bbf174.css" data-turbo-track="reload" />
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js",
    "custom": "/assets/custom/index-fd29fe543537735de09c23dfa7241cdd8e47c8f9fd71e89211b591fc7c12fd8c.js""
  }
}</script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js">
<script src="/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js" async="async" data-turbo-track="reload"></script>
<script type="module">import "application"</script>
```

My view.

```rb
<a class="btn" href="javascript: btn_project_show();">
```

When I click in the link, I can see this error into the javascript console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: btn_project_show is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:2
(anonymous) @ VM1642:1
```

What is wrong?

My knowledge of javascript is pretty basic. To my is all prefect.

**I don't want create a javascript module in *custom/index.js*. Just some custom funcions.**

Comment: maybe you need to add `import "custom.js"` on your `application.js`

Comment: @LamPhan, it was done. I forgot to mencion it. Thanks, I  will edit my post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom JS file to new rails 7 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548841/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-new-rails-7-project) I would note the top portion where it appears to suggest you need to import "custom/custom" because that is the import name shown in your import maps. Or scroll all the way down to the "Single files are easy"

Comment: @engineersmnky, that is what I read. Maybe I didn't understand what I read :-D. I'm going to reading again. thanks.

Comment: Try changing `import "custom"` to `import "custom/custom"` and see if it works. If so you have a solution (based on that answer) otherwise you have one more item you have tried.

Comment: you definitely need to `import "custom/custom"`. you would only get a directory mapping if you have a `custom/index.js` file (see "controllers"), then you could do `import "custom"` which imports index file. also you're working with modules and `btn_project_show` will need to be made global before you can use it that way `window.btn_project_show = function() { ...`, but probably better get familiar with Stimulus  https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/