# Rails 7: import javascript WITHOUT importmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I read [How to add custom JS file to new rails 7 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548841/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-new-rails-7-project) and I wrote [Rails 7: How to add custom javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77763801/rails-7-how-to-add-custom-javascript-functions)
I think now I have things clear.

I don't want to load a module. I just want to load a sigle javascript file with a few custom functions like this.

```js
function btn_project_show() {
    alert('culodemono');    
}
```

With this code... (and all the other things refereed in the posts above)

```html
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```

rails create this code... ( And I understand that importmap means the source is a javascript module, non a simple file with simple functions)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="J96RvzdbOjB5WdfZtE0-eFIoJpISdZP3N32YPIiotPmIsTBlGyL69NlqShdPCadKOv4ReV2PFoGdMZ9CH1kxdw" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-ed7f657c82113ab3654e0f1c0a9fb78eb9439717ba426d64a05914a481e366bf.css" data-turbo-track="reload" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendor-342cc5ede18e0d08cf0a816961342ad3262763c3e440dbabc6bca4f058bbf174.css" data-turbo-track="reload" />
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js",
    "custom": "/assets/custom/index-fd29fe543537735de09c23dfa7241cdd8e47c8f9fd71e89211b591fc7c12fd8c.js""
  }
}</script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js">
<script src="/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js" async="async" data-turbo-track="reload"></script>
<script type="module">import "application"</script>
```

But I just want this kind of link ( **but create by the assets pipeline with *rails assets:precompile***)

```html
<script src="/assets/custom/index-fd29fe543537735de09c23dfa7241cdd8e47c8f9fd71e89211b591fc7c12fd8c.js"></script>
```

Otherwhise, my simple javascript funtions are not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom/index", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Don't import that file anywhere else and remove the `pin` for it from importmap.rb.

---

Keep in mind you can still make functions with modules, they just have to be made global to be used outside of modules:

```js
window.btn_project_show = function() {
  alert('culodemono');
}
```